# rendering object through register helper with handlebars

Tags: html, templates, handlebars.js, helper

My object is like this

```
  {user:{name:"user1", role:"admin", roleId:1, status:1 },
  users:[{id:1, name:"user1", role:"admin", roleId:1, status:1 }, {id:2, name:"user2",   role:"user", roleId:2, status:2 }]
  roles:[{roleId:1, name="user"},{roleId:2, name="admin"}]
  };
```

My template is like this. I am iterating over users

```
  {{#users}}
 <div id="userRoleInfo">
            <input type="hidden" id="userId" value="{{id}}" />
            <div class="label">
                <label>User permission</label>
            </div>
            {{#checkUser ../user.roleId roleId ../roles}}
                <div >Administrator</div>
            {{else}} 
                <select id="selRoleId" data-custom="true">                                                   
                        <option value="0" >Assign Role</option>

                    //Problem is here. Its not displaying roles
                    {{#each roles}}
                        <option value="{{roleId}}">{{name}}</option>
                    {{/each}}

                </select> 
            {{/checkUser}}

       </div>

{{/users}}
```

my register helper is like this

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper("checkUser", function(loggedInUserRoleId, roleId,roles,  options) {
    if(loggedInUserRoleId == 1 && roleId < 2){
   return options.fn(this);
    }else{
  //return options.inverse(roles);
  return options.inverse(this); // I am not sure what should I do here so that it could display the roles in select tag
         }

    });
```

So I don't know how could I use roles object to display roles inside select tag.

Please let me know if there is confusion or you need more information

Comment: Have you tried `{{#each ../../roles}}`?

Comment: You are great mate its just working.. Thanks a lot!! Please put your answer I'll accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things behave the same inside an `{{else}}` as they do in any other block so you just need to `../` enough times to back up to where `roles` lives:

```
{{#each ../../roles}}
    <option value="{{roleId}}">{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```